Telethon import is not allowed

It worked well until yesterday, but suddenly an import error occurs.
The only thing I worked on yesterday was to delete vs code and edit plus, which is unrelated to Python, and delete the relevant content from the firewall.
How does this affect you?
No matter how many times you reinstall telethon and change the version, the results are the same.
What's the reason?
I hope it works properly
python version = 3.11
telethon version = 1.36.0

Sovled it...
the file name is telethon.py then it cannot work
